# Python Request How to retrive cookie for get request?

Tags: python, python-3.x, python-requests

I am trying to fetch some details from a website using requests module and I realize that I can't do without setting the cookie in a header. However, I am not able to understand how to retrieve this cookie.

If I copy the cookie using chrome developers tools and set as part of request it works, however after some time it expires and then I have to do copy paste again, is there a way I can do auto retrieval or renewal?

**Code:**

```
headers = {
    'user-agent': 'Mozilla/5.0 (Macintosh; Intel Mac OS X 10_12_6) AppleWebKit/537.36 (KHTML, like Gecko) Chrome/71.0.3578.98 Safari/537.36',
    'accept': 'text/html,application/xhtml+xml,application/xml;q=0.9,image/webp,image/apng,*/*;q=0.8',
    'accept-encoding': 'gzip, deflate, br',
    'cookie': 'visid_incap_820541=xigWzrvDQcSUJ0mvESKe+BR9KlwAAAAAQUIPAAAAAABRN2d88YW7aPzz88KJGqf2; optimizelyEndUserId=oeu1546288405916r0.23219734574282036; _gcl_au=1.1.1732703525.1546288407; _ga=GA1.2.125112106.1546288407; pCode=L7R 0B4; PageSize=15; AAMC_traderca_0=REGION%7C7; aam_uuid=61828363884759157680150590708572742734; .ASPXANONYMOUS=_6qGJdrX1AEkAAAANDYzYmFjYjMtOTVjMi00MzI0LWIyNTItOTZiNGNhOWUwYTI4YJzGhgZ555Ei_Iv_SWlhHlzaRMQ1; SearchResultOrderBy=PriceDesc; DealerLeadsPreTestKey=True; at_uid=mfAcGz813UijYm%2f9Gc2qqw%3d%3d; InternalSignInComplete=False; InternalSignInCompleteNew=False; cc_audpid=430e20732b28f2c7ba2d5be3182cf0ec; {E7ABF06F-D6A6-4c25-9558-3932D3B8A04D}=optimizelyEndUserId=oeu1546288405916r0.23219734574282036&pCode=L7R+0B4&PageSize=15&AAMC_traderca_0=REGION%257C7&cc_audpid=430e20732b28f2c7ba2d5be3182cf0ec&AMCVS_2650037254CC132F0A4C98A6%40AdobeOrg=1&culture=en-ca&uag=69962FE6D5D8F6D8A13AA09DEAA150E0AF8ACC624C0681A20A7E9500C633BA4F&SortOrder=PriceDesc&AMCV_2650037254CC132F0A4C98A6%40AdobeOrg=1099438348%257CMCIDTS%257C17902%257CMCMID%257C61762905408050898680174600361146729466%257CMCAAMLH-1546893208%257C7%257CMCAAMB-1547408986%257CRKhpRz8krg2tLO6pguXWp5olkAcUniQYPHaMWWgdJ3xzPWQmdj0y%257CMCOPTOUT-1546811386s%257CNONE%257CvVersion%257C2.1.0&srchLocation=%257B%2522Location%2522%3a%257B%2522Address%2522%3anull%2c%2522City%2522%3a%2522Burlington%2522%2c%2522Latitude%2522%3a43.38621%2c%2522Longitude%2522%3a-79.83713%2c%2522Province%2522%3a%2522ON%2522%2c%2522PostalCode%2522%3anull%2c%2522Type%2522%3a%2522%2522%257D%2c%2522UnparsedAddress%2522%3a%2522Burlington%2c%2520ON%2522%257D&searchState=%7b%22isUniqueSearch%22%3afalse%2c%22make%22%3a%22Honda%22%2c%22model%22%3a%22Civic%22%7d&lastsrpurl=%2fcars%2fhonda%2fcivic%2fon%2fburlington%2f&gtm_inmarket_search=true; __utmz=1.1547176815.1.1.utmcsr=(direct)|utmccn=(direct)|utmcmd=(none); SortOrder=PriceDesc; nlbi_820541_1646237=PMSfBHhxEHYkcGWQCOa5EgAAAAA4tf9PayhQkLrUhubKcWP7; AMCVS_2650037254CC132F0A4C98A6%40AdobeOrg=1; ASP.NET_SessionId=bcm0ercgtdwelfb0dgdj21vk; culture=en-ca; nlbi_820541_1646235=9pBCfqSeBlaU/rZuCOa5EgAAAACsm/k0oZhXrHPgQUgIdx2f; __utmc=1; 359_MVT=Production; incap_ses_677_820541=TuyqcgMGP0m7jlSD9TBlCfUdSlwAAAAAxKFz0lmbGa9NKShPYAlkCQ==; incap_ses_1002_820541=3YXVWNg2qgVt4jzJPNLnDaBFS1wAAAAAqTH+dOhbKju7PE7ya/m6JA==; incap_ses_530_820541=g8iydJkbsko61boENvFaB4ybTFwAAAAAAUoqmF8+aQR3K0DMuEkVxw==; _fbp=fb.1.1548524429333.920537732; _gid=GA1.2.216334428.1548524430; AMCV_2650037254CC132F0A4C98A6%40AdobeOrg=1099438348%7CMCIDTS%7C17922%7CMCMID%7C61762905408050898680174600361146729466%7CMCAAMLH-1549129230%7C7%7CMCAAMB-1549129230%7CRKhpRz8krg2tLO6pguXWp5olkAcUniQYPHaMWWgdJ3xzPWQmdj0y%7CMCOPTOUT-1548531630s%7CNONE%7CvVersion%7C2.1.0; srchLocation=%7B%22Location%22:%7B%22Address%22:null,%22City%22:%22Burlington%22,%22Latitude%22:43.3377685546875,%22Longitude%22:-79.80254364013672,%22Province%22:%22ON%22,%22PostalCode%22:%22L7R%200B4%22,%22Type%22:%22%22%7D,%22UnparsedAddress%22:%22L7R0B4%22%7D; lastsrpurl=/cars/honda/accord/on/burlington/?rcp=15&rcs=0&srt=3&trim=EX-L%2CEX-L%20w-Navi%2CSport%2CTouring&yRng=2014%2C&pRng=%2C17500&prx=25&prv=Ontario&loc=L7R0B4&trans=Automatic&hprc=True&wcp=True&sts=New-Used&nod=4%2B%20Door&inMarket=advancedSearch; searchState={"isUniqueSearch":false,"make":"Honda","model":"Accord"}; uag=DD83109745972DB18984A1EEEA659BA45124E731A1CA35CF766CEB2C78CDA978; PreviouslyViewedPVs=5-42423732%2c5-42065851%2c5-42244841%2c5-42278097%2c5-41992218%2c19-10936588%2c5-42160387%2c5-42241651%2c5-41965246%2c5-42082483%2c5-37819580%2c5-41702376%2c5-42242890%2c5-41373481%2c5-41778296%2c5-41482594%2c19-10932841%2c19-10932842%2c5-42444524%2c5-42424838%2c5-42293767%2c19-10923281%2c19-10930137%2c5-41790203%2c5-41136493%2c19-10902368%2c19-10918059%2c5-42386690%2c5-42192341%2c5-41718075; searchFlag=true; __utma=1.125112106.1546288407.1548216821.1548525035.9; __utmt=1; __utmb=1.4.9.1548525052914; _4c_=jVNdb9sgFP0rFa9LY8CA7bx1nbRWWtuHds8RH9eJFddYQJZlUf77LmnSLq20DckycM79PuzIZgkDmTEpasklYyVrxISsYBvJbEdC5%2FLvB5kRJhpFTQVClFWtJLeVsla2LeXQmLY1ZEJ%2BZj9SUCXwU6zaT0iwJ%2FsU1vCOU9GGZk46clrdR%2FhAkUixg%2B3%2FSVqE9uQpl0MF5VwKpj6QFZLdcErMQavXfTrLTXLRlAxp3SvrHY6Oa8RbE06M7RujkRzDsypX9%2FzWQqCSNwqXYU4ooZgpuZGWKUMZdUa9OpA1U5yqUuUU7Hi035F1wC6QZUpjnBXFZrOZ6nXyKWgHYWp1oYsbPzhdXFnrg%2Fv0CE4PxWe06oZF8kPxMCQdOl%2FIueCCl1XJ5w%2F3nNKacZZnrxhORBWYh%2FUO8tCbaTWleE6%2F8HRZ0ryHIRczhtySMXi3tmmetmPmb8BcRLdCoIvf%2FGIB7hb7TO7x4kbHa4%2FxbQL3CH0P4QiY4DfxcLpeBv8MFxXDW4%2F6I3fa4jZACyEcGHiKXcqRzgo%2FXqNqz5DLAzLmbEvc9N7qPtui4LPXsdfbeZ7O%2FwwmQoydHw50Km3VWqksVwJkpcHIxijRGFM1lpn8FL5ezb%2FffskdzI%2BKM6qmqEnF6xoV%2BIL%2FDX4KHTYv3EFa%2BhzxCevpEsbXPXnR7h%2Bydah6YnuNCVoHcZX8SPZHKYlaMSZkSfOrTgnlUytB89rv978B'
}

resp = requests.get(
    "https://www.autotrader.ca/",
    # "https://www.autotrader.ca/a/Honda/Accord+Sedan/Burlington/Ontario/5_42423732_ON20081215113610906/",
    headers=headers)

print(resp.status_code)
```

Answer (score 0):

You can use `cookies.get_dict()` to get the cookies using requests. If you need the `Set-Cookie` response sent by the server, it will be present in the response headers.

```
import requests
s = requests.Session()
r=s.get('http://www.google.com')
sep="\n------------------\n"
print(r.headers,end=sep)
print(r.headers['Set-Cookie'],end=sep)
print(r.cookies.get_dict())
```

Output

```
{'Date': 'Sat, 26 Jan 2019 20:59:50 GMT', 'Expires': '-1', 'Cache-Control': 'private, max-age=0', 'Content-Type': 'text/html; charset=ISO-8859-1', 'P3P': 'CP="This is not a P3P policy! See g.co/p3phelp for more info."', 'Content-Encoding': 'gzip', 'Server': 'gws', 'Content-Length': '5360', 'X-XSS-Protection': '1; mode=block', 'X-Frame-Options': 'SAMEORIGIN', 'Set-Cookie': '1P_JAR=2019-01-26-20; expires=Mon, 25-Feb-2019 20:59:50 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.com, NID=156=DqD5DO6OULcovwiJYJF3fFCU6FDUPP9xqCjdIzMVA48TXdk46ZMV-MeJl5Eg_4chXeZHAtKT-WiIEAiRFXSH8SF_riyegpizTr1xQFegMu2dF7rFpCuWnL8IlBhEtp6BYwUHYifWxUzBIQjAnKVbz1_am1j2vW90QsRkNpiDqvw; expires=Sun, 28-Jul-2019 20:59:50 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.com; HttpOnly'}
------------------
1P_JAR=2019-01-26-20; expires=Mon, 25-Feb-2019 20:59:50 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.com, NID=156=DqD5DO6OULcovwiJYJF3fFCU6FDUPP9xqCjdIzMVA48TXdk46ZMV-MeJl5Eg_4chXeZHAtKT-WiIEAiRFXSH8SF_riyegpizTr1xQFegMu2dF7rFpCuWnL8IlBhEtp6BYwUHYifWxUzBIQjAnKVbz1_am1j2vW90QsRkNpiDqvw; expires=Sun, 28-Jul-2019 20:59:50 GMT; path=/; domain=.google.com; HttpOnly
------------------
{'1P_JAR': '2019-01-26-20', 'NID': '156=DqD5DO6OULcovwiJYJF3fFCU6FDUPP9xqCjdIzMVA48TXdk46ZMV-MeJl5Eg_4chXeZHAtKT-WiIEAiRFXSH8SF_riyegpizTr1xQFegMu2dF7rFpCuWnL8IlBhEtp6BYwUHYifWxUzBIQjAnKVbz1_am1j2vW90QsRkNpiDqvw'}
```

You can also take a look at [Requests Session Objects](http://docs.python-requests.org/en/master/user/advanced/#session-objects) which allows you to persist certain parameters across requests.

```
import requests
s = requests.Session()
r=s.get("https://www.autotrader.ca/")
print(s.cookies.get_dict())
```

Output

```
{'359_MVT': 'Beta', 'incap_ses_427_820268': 'CH+XZmtI+XAoSGd5jgPtBYbSTFwAAAAAisPp/ga12qcaus8OQBy+WQ==', 'incap_ses_427_820541': '5w7HIplKciGGR2d5jgPtBYXSTFwAAAAAtK6JqBFZ7yOfMEQRTxsb4w==', 'nlbi_820541_1646237': '6PXif98z32ITUgWNCOa5EgAAAAB0qBmvDiWBSIKScEbsrrei', 'visid_incap_820268': '8Y9/QUrMSN6ig2Eh8yaQBobSTFwAAAAAQUIPAAAAAAC3xP7V2sSXvYIv1o3+boYi', 'visid_incap_820541': 'GTvhgGUCSPiBzrX555BMD4XSTFwAAAAAQUIPAAAAAADrOrmirYySt7jxsjvAx4e6', '___utmvavlufwBX': 'FRU\x01rTwc', '___utmvbvlufwBX': 'JZt\r\n    XUhORalX: Ltz', '___utmvmvlufwBX': 'ISmGYgcVGsA'}
```

That being said, i don't think Requests is the tool for the job here. [Selenium](https://selenium-python.readthedocs.io) can be used to scrape these kinds of websites.

Eg. Printing the headline from your commented url

```
from selenium import webdriver
from time import sleep
driver = webdriver.Firefox()
driver.get('https://www.autotrader.ca/a/Honda/Accord+Sedan/Burlington/Ontario/5_42423732_ON20081215113610906/')
title = driver.find_element_by_css_selector('h1').text
print(title)
```

Output

```
2014 Honda Accord EX-L|SERVICE HISTORY ON FILE - Burlington
```